# Unique Address from google maps api

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kml

I am using togeojson for converting kml to togeojson
I am getting latitude and longitude from geometry.

I am sending alt & long using google API for getting address this is my jquery code:

```
for (var i = 0, l = begin.length; i < l; i+=2) {
    var OddpositionVal = begin[i];
    var EvenpositionVal = begin[i + 1];
    var longitude11=OddpositionVal;
    var latitude11=EvenpositionVal;
    //console.log("latitude:"+latitude10);
    //console.log("longitude:"+longitude10);
    var latlng10 = latitude11+","+longitude11;
    //console.log("latlng10:"+latlng10);
    //var address=[];
    var url1 = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+latlng10;
    //console.log("url:"+url1);
    $.getJSON(url1, function (data) {
        //console.log("data:"+data.results.length);
        for(var i=0;i<data.results.length;i++) {
            newAddress.push(data.results[0].formatted_address);
            //console.log("Properties:"+properties);

        }

    });
}
```

When I do console.log(newAddress), I am getting repeated locations:

[Iam getting duplicates of locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CEsg.png)

Can anyone help me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/rajacharya/NNuDe/599/

I have updated code to remove duplicate values please find below

http://jsfiddle.net/rajacharya/NNuDe/628/

```
var latlng = "55.397563, 10.39870099999996";
var newAddress = [];
var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latlng;
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    for(var i=0;i<data.results.length;i++) {
        var adress = data.results[i].formatted_address;
        newAddress.push(data.results[0].formatted_address);
    }
    alert(newAddress);
});
```

Note that the reverse geocoder returned more than one result. The "formatted_address" results are not just postal addresses, but any way to geographically name a location. For example, when geocoding a point in the city of Chicago, the geocoded point may be denoted as a street address, as the city (Chicago), as its state (Illinois) or as a country (The United States). All are "addresses" to the geocoder. The reverse geocoder returns any of these types as valid results.

The reverse geocoder matches political entities (countries, provinces, cities and neighborhoods), street addresses, and postal codes.

Generally, addresses are returned from most specific to least specific; the more exact address is the most prominent result, as it is in this case. Note that we return different types of addresses, from the most specific street address to less specific political entities such as neighborhoods, cities, counties, states, etc.

The following example filters the addresses returned to include only those with address type of street_address.

```
var latlng = "12.9715987, 77.5945627";
var newAddress = [];
var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latlng +"&result_type=street_address&key=YOUR_API_KEY";
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    for(var i=0;i<data.results.length;i++) {
        var adress = data.results[i].formatted_address;
        newAddress.push(data.results[0].formatted_address);
    }
    alert(newAddress);
});
```

Replace YOUR_API_KEY with key value

Comment: @karthik, if u use this one it will return all the possible combination based on this (countries, provinces, cities and neighborhoods), street addresses, and postal codes. That's y it is creating same addresses multiple times some time.

If pass &result_type=street_address&key=YOUR_API_KEY" in url, it will filter the result which have proper street address

Comment: Replace API_KEY with your API value registered in the google geocoding api

Comment: For this latitude =12.9715987 and longitude = 77.5945627 the address is "24/1, Vittal Mallya Rd, KG Halli, Shanthala Nagar, Ashok Nagar, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560001, India" and i don't want remaining...can you please help me!! iam trying this from two days :(

Comment: Update tge lat and lang with any value

Comment: thanks bro its work like a charm i really so thankful to you it means a lot you saved me